# Loops with if statements classifying numbers

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am having trouble with a loop I am creating.  My intention is that the loop will see where a value falls and give that value another name. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
a<-rnorm(10,0,1)
b<-rnorm(10,0,1)

testing<-data.frame(a,b)

testing2<-testing
for (i in 1:nrow(testing2)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(testing2)){
    if (testing2[i,j]>1) testing2[i,j]<-"More"
    else if (testing2[i,j]<(-1)) testing2[i,j]<-"Less"
    else testing2[i,j]<-"Same"
  }
}
```

When I look at testing2 and compare it to testing, it does not match what it should be doing.  "More" seems to work, but it gets mixed up between "Less" and "Same".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a (nested) loop, use the vectorised [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) instead:

```
testing = ifelse(testing > 1, 'More', ifelse(testing < -1, 'Less', 'Same'))
```

Answer (score 5):

`cut` comes to mind as an obvious candidate here. Since you need to apply it across multiple columns, you can use `lapply` as follows:

```
x <- testing
x[] <- lapply(testing, cut, breaks=c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf), 
              labels=c("less", "same", "more"))
x
```

^^*edited with refinements from the comments ;-)*

Or with `as.matrix` instead of `lapply`...

```
x <- cut(as.matrix(testing), c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf), 
         labels=c("less", "same", "more"))
dim(x) <- dim(testing)
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it, although I was going to go with the more compact `lapply(testing, cut, breaks=c(-Inf, -1, 1, Inf), labels=c("less", "same", "more"))`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, I need to break my habit of unnecessary anonymous functions :-)

Comment: Worse habits exist. I like your use of `x[]`, this never occurred to me.

Comment: `cut` was the function I was missing, and hence ended up with the (horrible) nested `ifelse`. Very nice. An addition to Matthew’s remark about the unnecessary lambda I just wanted to add that the assignment (`A <- …`) is also unnecessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, ha! That was a relic of me originally thinking about if `factor` would work before I remembered `cut`. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, there are better ways of doing this. But coming back to your code, you are messing things up by assigning a `character` to `numeric` type.

In R `data.frame` the columns have the same type. Therefore once you assign a character, the entire column type becomes character.

You can verify this by calling `sapply(testing2, class)` before and after the for loops